# DELETE & PUT verbs are dropped from extensionlessUrlHandler

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5

In IIS on Win2K8 Std, I have added DELETE and PUT verbs by clicking on the server name in IIS Manager then going to Handler Mappings.

I then Edit these 3 names : ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0, ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit, ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit and click the Request Restrictions... button select verbs tab and add ,DELETE,PUT to the verbs then click OK & OK.

These verbs will stay on these for a period of time month or two then it seems like a Windows patch happens and they are lost.

It doesn't happen consistently either last night it only happened to 1 of the 2 boxes in my web farm.

Any ideas what causes this?  Any way to make these the defaults that IIS gets set back to?

EDIT:
Happened today after patches early on 10/9/13.  Happened on the same box as before of the 2 in the farm.  Might be something flaky in that box and should ground and recreated.